# Generic List AddRange() type safety

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, generics

Ironically, while converting a bunch of old Arraylists to use generic List(Of foo) collections, to improve type safety, I encountered an unexpected behaviour in the `List.AddRange()` method.

Given the following code, I would have expected a compiler error, but I don't get one, and the project runs until the AddRange call, where an *'Unable to cast List(Of bar) to List(Of foo)'* exception is thrown.

```
Dim barList As List(Of bar) = BarFunctionsLib.GetBarList()

Dim fooList As New List(Of foo)
fooList.AddRange(barList)
```

Shouldn't my attempt to pass a List(Of bar) into an AddRange method on a List(Of foo) be picked up by the compiler? I've not been through my compiler settings in VS2015, perhaps they've been fiddled with in the past and now let this through?

Any ideas would be appreciated, as the whole justification of putting work into converting Arraylists to generic Lists was to prevent errors like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to turn on `Option Strict` to get a compiler error about this - the simplest way is to put

```
Option Strict On
```

at the top of your source file.

A more robust solution for existing projects is to go to your project properties, and in the Compile section set it globally for your project.

As [Tim mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389061/generic-list-addrange-type-safety/44389128#comment75777800_44389128) however, the very best solution is to change your settings to default it on for all new VB projects:
[image]

Comment: The simplest and best it to change default project settings to `option strict on`. [screenshot of option-setting](http://i.imgur.com/55C3SMh.jpg)

Comment: Brilliant that's great, thanks. I'm working on a legacy VB.net project after years of c#, and what I found after turning on Option Strict for the whole project just made me feel very sad... *sigh*

Comment: You can probably find even more if you turn off Option Infer :-) Go on you know you want to!